# Is ASP .Net jQuery AJAX login safe?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I'm trying to create a login form in ASP.NET, in which I have two options, the first is the traditional posting back to server and the other one is using jQuery ajax in validating the user credentials... Now here are my questions:

Which do you think is better? 
Will there be some security issues if u use jQuery ajax to pass the data to codebehind?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you are not sending it over HTTPS then It won't matter

Answer (score 4):

As long as the connection to the server is at least encrypted, the method used to post the information has no important difference.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. I just don't know why my question was voted down by some user, I see no wrong with that. I hope he learn to show respect to newbie programmers.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly to authenticate a username/password, that is just as safe as submitting a login form to the same location. The security problem would come from what you're doing (or not doing) in the success function and future ajax requests as javascript can be forged/changed on the fly to tamper with variables (userid notably) you have set.